# Exception while removing items from a collection inside a delegate

Tags: c#, invoke

I have `List<ActiveDeviceProcess>` which keeps the windows forms. When I call the `activeDeviceProcessFormClosed(deviceNumber)` from another form via `FormClosing` listener. I got an error. But I don't know why. Everything look like fine. Here is my method:

```
public void activeDeviceProcessFormClosed(int deviceNumber)
{
     this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
         foreach (ActiveDeviceProcess i in activeDeviceProcessForms)
         {
             if (i.device.deviceNumber == deviceNumber)
             {
                 activeDeviceProcessForms.Remove(i);
             }
         }
     });
}
```

Here is the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove items from a collection while iterating it. Use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) instead:

```
public void activeDeviceProcessFormClosed(int deviceNumber)
{
     this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
        activeDeviceProcessForms.RemoveAll(i => i.Device.DeviceNumber == deviceNumber);
     });
}
```

**Edit:**

If you only have multiple items with the same device id want to remove the first element that has that `DeviceNumber`, you can use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` and `List<T>.Remove`:

```
public void activeDeviceProcessFormClosed(int deviceNumber)
{
     this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
        var device = activeDeviceProcessForms.FirstOrDefault(
                        i => i.Device.DeviceNumber == deviceNumber);

        if (device != null)
            activeDeviceProcessForms.Remove(device);
     });
}
```

Comment: But I need to remove specific one. However you enlighten me. I solved the problem by adding "break"

Comment: @a-f-a Do you have multiple elements with the same device number? Perhaps my edit will be more fit.

Comment: OK. This one works too. I thought it removes all the elements in List. Thank you.

Comment: @a-f-a It only removes the elements that yield true for the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is iterating, when I remove an element inside the list I should add "break" command.

```
public void activeDeviceProcessFormClosed(int deviceNumber)
{
     this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
     {
         foreach (ActiveDeviceProcess i in activeDeviceProcessForms)
         {
             if (i.device.deviceNumber == deviceNumber)
             {
                 activeDeviceProcessForms.Remove(i);
                 break;//----> this was added.
             }
         }
     });
}
```